# Should I make my Executor service instance static that is defined on class level?

Tags: java, static, executorservice

I have a class where I am using Executor Service with a fixed number of threads in my thread pool which execute multiple short running tasks.

My code is like this:

```
public class MessageConsumer{

private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

main(){
.....
}

receiveMessage(String message){
try{
     executor.execute(new FileWriterTask(message))
     ......
   }catch(Exception e){
       ........
       executor.shutDown();
       .........
   }
}

.....
}
```

So as you can see I have defined and instantiated my Executor Service at the class level
and using it inside the methods. I have made it private and there is no method to access it from 
outside.

I was wondering whether I should mark my Executor service instance **static** as well, because that would mean, only one instance per class. Currently also, it will be only one per class, I guess. What would be a good practice?
What would be a good design to declare the Executor Service?

Comment: Don't use static state. (Immutable items are fine, such as a `Logger` instance, but an executor has state.)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- thanks for the tip, can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating multiple instances of `MessageConsumer` class, then you may have a use case to share the `ExecutorService` instance and so you *can* make it static.

But if you are creating only instance of `MessageConsumer`, prefer **not** to use static, so that you can have dependency injection and thus have testable components.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have 2 questions: 1. To have testable components via dependency injection, is it like the instance should not be static? 2. In my current scope, there will be only one instance of 'MessageConsumer' class, but even if I want to share the Executor service instance, static won't be necessary right? I can either provide a method to access the instance or change access modifier. What do you think?